# How to move all 'c' elements to the end with a recursive function using Kotlin?

Tags: function, kotlin, recursion

How can I write code that returns the following output for this input:

Input:    ->  fffcccfff
Output:   ->  ffffffccc

My code so far:

```
fun toEnd(s: String): String {
    if (s[0] == 'x') {
        return (s.substring(1)) + s[0]
    } else {
        return s[0] + toEnd(s.substring(1))
    }
}
```

But that doesn't work for the input above.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried.  See [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: my code:
fun toEnd(s: String): String {

    if (s[0] == 'x') {
        return (s.substring(1)) + s[0]

    } else {
        return s[0] + toEnd(s.substring(1))
    }
}
but thats doesnt work true like input: fffcccfff   output:  ffffffccc
so how can i remove my code for true???

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three problems here.  To take the most serious first:

- **There's no termination condition.**

You can't recurse for ever; there must be a point at which you stop.

As written, your code throws a `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`, because it keeps calling itself for smaller and smaller strings; eventually, it calls itself on an empty string, and so the `s[0]` fails because there *is* no first character.

To fix this, you need to add a check that does something different if the string is small enough. You could check for an empty string, and just return the empty string; or you could check for a string with ≤ 1 characters, and return it (which avoids one last level of recursion).

- **It checks for the wrong character.**

The question (and the desired output) asks about moving the letter 'c' to the end of the string; but the code tries to move the letter 'x' instead.

(Of course, this is trivial to fix.)

- **It doesn't recurse if the first character is matched.**

So it will only ever move *one* instance of that character to the end.

To fix that, simply call `toEnd()` on the substring in both cases.

Here's a fixed version. (I've also converted it to a `when` and made it an expression body; that's not necessary, but illustrates the alternatives.)

```
fun toEnd(s: String): String = when {
    s.length <= 1 -> s
    s[0] == 'c' -> toEnd(s.substring(1)) + s[0]
    else -> s[0] + toEnd(s.substring(1))
}
```

This is a good example of recursion. But it's probably worth noting that you wouldn't write production code like that, because it's very inefficient, creating shedloads of temporary String objects.